# Why do I need to run source command for making .bash_profile alias available?

Tags: command-line, bash

My `.bash_profile` is like below:

```
alias l='ls -l'
alias p='pwd'
alias sites='cd /home/caveman/sites'
alias time_card='cd /home/caveman/sites/time-card/time-card'
alias ping='ping google.com'
alias bash_profile='gedit /home/caveman/.bash_profile'
alias webroot='cd /var/www'
```

every time I log into my machine I need to run the `source .bash_profile` to make all the alias available.

Can you guys figure out where is the problem is?

Comment: Take a look here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal
There is a good explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~/.bash_profile` is only read in login session.

Also, having a `~/.bash_profile` prevents the sourcing of `~/.profile`, that is the preferred file to use for login shell in the `bash` configuration for Ubuntu.

When you log in the Display Manager (I suppose GDM), the `~/.profile` is read by default (I don't know if GDM follows `bash` rules and read `~/.bash_profile` instead, if exists).

Even if `~/.bash_profile` were read from GDM, aliases are not inherited, so 
the shell you have in a graphics terminal (that is not a login shell) cannot see them.

The solution is: put your aliases in `~/.bashrc`, and use aliases only for very simple things, otherwise use functions.

The file `~/.bashrc` is read by non-login interactive shells, and is sourced in `~/.profile`, so that its content is also available in login shells.

Comment: I see,in MAC OSX the bash profile works for alias as why I tried same in ubuntu,thanks for your navigation :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the aliases to ~/.bash_aliases instead