# Why ~/.bash_profile is not getting sourced when opening a terminal?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, source, .profile

## Problem

I have an Ubuntu 11.04 Virtual Machine and I wanted to set up my Java development environment. I did as follows

1. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`
2. Added the following entries to **~/.bash_profile**

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk

   export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```
3. Save the changes and exit
4. Open up a terminal again and typed the following

   ```
   echo $JAVA_HOME   (blank)
   echo $PATH        (displayed, but not the JAVA_HOME value)
   ```
5. Nothing happened, like if the export of JAVA_HOME and it's addition to the PATH were never done.

## Solution

I had to go to **~/.bashrc** and add the following entry towards the end of file

```
#Source bash_profile to set JAVA_HOME and add it to the PATH because for some reason is not being picked up
. ~/.bash_profile
```

## Questions

1. Why did I have to do that? I thought bash_profile, bash_login or profile in absence of those two get executed first before bashrc.
2. Was in this case my terminal a **non-login** shell?
3. If so, why when doing su after the terminal and putting the password it did not execute profile where I had also set the exports mentioned above?

Comment: Accepted answer mentioned "Sourcing `~/.bash_profile` from `~/.bashrc` is the wrong solution. It's supposed to be the other way around; `~/.bash_profile` should source `~/.bashrc`." How come your solution opposite to that?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is only sourced by bash when started in login mode. That is typically when you log in at the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>..<kbd>F6</kbd>), connect via ssh, or use `sudo -i` or `su -` to run commands as another user.

When you log in graphically, `~/.profile` will be specifically sourced by the script that launches gnome-session (or whichever desktop environment you're using). So `~/.bash_profile` is not sourced at all when you log in graphically.

When you open a terminal, the terminal starts bash in (non-login) interactive mode, which means it will source `~/.bashrc`.

The right place for you to put these environment variables is in `~/.profile`, and the effect should be apparent next time you log in.

Sourcing `~/.bash_profile` from `~/.bashrc` is the wrong solution. It's supposed to be the other way around; `~/.bash_profile` should source `~/.bashrc`.

See [DotFiles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles) for a more thorough explanation, including some history of why it is like it is.

(On a side note, when installing openjdk via apt, symlinks should be set up by the package, so that you don't really need to set `JAVA_HOME` or change `PATH`)

Comment: symlinks whre setup by the package by JAVA_HOME and it's addition to the PATH where not that is why I was doing what I was doing. I deleted the bash_profile and added my exports in **.profile**. Restarted my Virtual Machine and indeed I was able to do **echo $JAVA-HOME**

Comment: I've found that when opening a Terminal from the sidebar in Ubuntu 12 the ~/.profile file is not loaded.

Comment: @jcollum That's good. `.profile` should only be sourced when you log in.

Comment: oh, opening a terminal is not the same as logging in... I was thinking logging in _to the terminal_.

Comment: I've found that personal additions to be sourced *each time when opening a Terminal* do get loaded when placed on `.bash_aliases`. Would that be a better solution?

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro that's because your `~/.bashrc` sources `~/.bash_aliases`. The few times you need to change an environment variable; update `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`, then log out and back in.

Comment: I know, that's why I added my additional code there. What I wanted to do was to configure options for the terminal (e.g. the prompt), but these were not loaded if I set them on `.profile`, even after a full restart.

Comment: @JuanA.Navarro Ah, you mean `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` etc? Those are not environment variables, and they do indeed belong in `~/.bashrc` as they only make sense for interactive shells.

Comment: If you are using (the Ubuntu standard) Gnome Terminal, you can do Edit->Profile Preferences, go to the Title and Command tab, and check "Run command as a login shell". It will then source your .bash_profile or .profile whenever you open a terminal, as you probably expected it to.

Comment: Bear in mind that `.profile` is ignored by bash if `.bash_profile` exists. See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/570323/151431)  and `man bash` for more details.

Comment: @terdon, yes, but bash is not involved when logging in graphically, so it goes straight for `.profile`.

Comment: @geirha how the-structure-that-changes-state-when-you-login-from-console is called (foo-session?) and where it is to be found, opposed to merely starting an interactive shell? (in case it's called 'login' where is it to be found?) I did `man -k login` then `man 1 login` and see `/var/run/utmp/` and `login session`, however not the corresponding kernel-or-whatever structure.

Comment: [This flowchart](https://medium.com/@rajsek/zsh-bash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc-e30045652f2e) states that `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or `.profile` are sourced with a login shell, whether the shell is interactive or not doesn't matter. Is the flowchart wrong, or should the answer be modified?

Comment: @AntoninDécimo thanks! Took nearly 9 years for someone to notice my error. I've edited the answer.

Comment: `and the effect should be apparent next time you log in.` There's my answer! I just needed to log out and log back in for all shells being opened to have already sourced `~/.profile` before opening.

Answer (score 65):

You can check if your Bash shell is started as a login-shell by running:

```
shopt login_shell
```

If the reply is `off` you are not running a login shell.

Read the Bash manual's *invocation* section on how Bash reads (or does not read) different configuration files.

Excerpt from `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell  with  the `--login`  option,  it  first  reads
>   and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file
>   exists.  After reading that file, it  looks  for  `~/.bash_profile`, 
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`,  in  that  order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

`su` on the other hand also does not start a login shell by default, you have to tell it to do so by using the `--login` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the **shotp login_shell** command. Awesome!!

Answer (score 42):

I think it is worth mentioning that you can change the default of gnome-terminal to use a login shell (ie. bash -l) by editing the profile preferences.

go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command tab
check the "Run command as a login shell" option

Comment: What are the downsides to enabling this setting?

Comment: @chris you are just loading code a little more code than necessary in a lot of occasion. It probably doesn't matter if your ``~/.bash_profile`` is evaluating really quickly, which is probably the case. A good thing to check is to chase out any calls to other processes that are usually quite costly.

Comment: I checked the 'Run command as a login shell' but now every time I open a terminal, I get `-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching`"`
`-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Answer (score 18):

If you open a terminal or run `su` the shell is not executed as a login shell but as a normal interactive shell. So it reads `~/.bashrc` but not `~/.bash_profile`. You can run `su` with the `-l` option to make it run your shell as a login shell.

When you are working with a GUI the shell is usually never run as a login shell so it's usually fine to put all yout stuff in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That is what I had done and it worked, but check what the guy in the bottom says, he suggests is a bad idea to put it in bashrc and put it on the profile instead. ....Hey both ways work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**

In classical recommended ubuntu setup, `~/.bash_profile` gets evaluated only in specific occasions. And it makes sense.

Put your stuff in `~/.bashrc`, it'll get evaluated everytime.

**Ok, I want to understand, why does this make sense ?**

Keypoints to understand what is going on:

- all **processes** on linux have and **uses environment** variables
- environment variables are **inherited**
- thus setting them **once on the father** of all your process is enough
  (especially if it requires some computation time.)
- the father of all your process is typically launched after you 
  **log in** on your device (give your credentials).
- there are things you might want to do only once when you log in on
  your computer (check for new mail for instance...).

So "login" time is typically:

- In console mode, when you login (with Ctrl-Alt F1) or through `ssh`,
  as the shell will be the father of all process, it'll load your 
  `~/.bash_profile`.
- In graphic mode, when you open your session, the first process 
  (`gnome-session` for classical ubuntu) will be in charge to read
  `.profile`.

**Ok, so where to put my stuff ?**

It's rather complex, the [full story is here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles). But here is a run down
that is pretty common for ubuntu users. So considering that:

- you use `bash` shell,
- you have a `~/.bash_profile` and follow the **recommendation** to add 
  the loading of `~/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_profile` so as to get 
  at least **one file that gets evaluated whatever is the invocation 
  mecanism**.

This is a quick suggestion of where to put things.

- *~/.bashrc*  (Gets **evaluated in all occasion**, provided you follow the recommendation)

  For **fast-evaluation** environment variable and code for your 
  **user-only** and **bash-only** command-line usage (aliases for 
  instance). **bashism** are welcome.

  It gets loaded on itself upon:

  - make a new shell window/pane in graphical sessions.
  - calling `bash`
  - `screen` new pane or tab. (not `tmux` !)
  - any bash instance in a graphical console client 
    (`terminator`/`gnome-terminal`...) if you **don't tick** 
    option "run command as login shell".

  And it will get loaded in all the other occasion thanks to the prior recommendation.
- *~/.bash_profile*  (Gets **evaluated in specific occasion only**)

  For **slow-evaluation** environment variable and code for your **user-only** and **console-session** processes. 
  **bashism** are welcome.
  It gets loaded on:

  - console login (Ctrl-Alt F1),
  - ssh logins to this machine,
  - `tmux` new pane or windows (default settings), (not `screen` !)
  - explicit calls of `bash -l`,
  - any bash instance in a graphical console client 
    (`terminator`/`gnome-terminal`...) **only if** you tick 
    option "run command as login shell".
- *~/.profile*  (Gets evaluated only in graphical-session)

  For **slow-evaluation** environment variables and with **no-bashism**
  for your **user-only** and all **graphical-session** processes. It gets 
  loaded upon login in your graphical UI.

Comment: On the occasions that bash does load a profile file, it will load `.profile` if `.bash_profile` does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation. it helps newbies like me. In Mac Mojave , if I put variables in ~/.bashrc and do source, and then if I do `env` I don't see env variables set (I tried closing iTerm and re-opening). But I notice that when I installed Android studio and other apps, all those env vars were set in `/.bash_profile` . So When I added in `/.bash_profile` it worked like charm. Why is that?

Comment: Something that troubles me about this: say that someone puts cosmetic junk/fun things into `~/.bashrc` (like screenfetch / figlet stuff etc) so that they get some output on opening a console. Then, if they run a one line shell script that does some simple thing, that is going to always hit `.bashrc`. Therefore, it seems crazy to put everything into `.bashrc`. Also, what then is the point of `.bash_profile` if you put everything into `.bashrc`? I don't get it. Linux / bash usually make sense but this is all seems a convoluted and self-contradictory mess made up by a drunk person.

Comment: To be specific: • If I want code to run in both graphical and interactive login shells, where should I put that code? • If I want code to run just in graphical terminals, where should I put that code? • If I want code to only run in interactive login shells, where should I put that code? The answer seems to be "umm, bash is just a broken confusing mess, just put the code anywhere then  try to insert weird connecting chains to try and make things dotsource other things". It's all really weird ... right?

Comment: @YorSubs You're not wrong. The fundamental thing to understand is `.bashrc` is what is executed when BASH is loaded. What you do from there if up to you. I would agree with you that dotsourcing other things is unnecessary, but I believe that practice was started by developers trying to separate the generated code in the `.bashrc` from their custom code `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `sudo su` the shell is not executed, instead of that try with `sudo su -` this will load `~/.bash_profile` as source by default.

Answer (score 0):

They want you to put it in ~/.bash_aliases now

in ~/.bashrc there is this code pointing it out:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Comment: Not really. It's for aliases, not for env variables.