# "Can't open" an /opt file

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, bashrc

This is my first post. I wanted to ask for any idea so to solve my problem. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and my purpose is to use OpenFoam CFD software.

I am trying to execute an script called Allrun that corresponds to a tutorial. I am using the sudo command like this.

```
sudo ./Allrun
```

then it asks for my password and after introducing it, it suddenly appears a message saying:

```
./Allrun: 5: .: Can't open /bin/tools/RunFunctions
```

This path appeares at line 5 as sourced in the script, so like:

```
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/RunFunctions
```

being $WM_PROJECT_DIR a variable defined in opt/openfoam22/etc/bashrc and pointing the directory:

```
$WM_PROJECT_DIR= /opt/openfoam222
```

(this bashrc is at the same time sourced in ~/.bashrc file, and I can use the variable in the terminal, so I assume it is allright sourced)

I have tried also to chmod the RunFunctions file with rwx permissions, and veryfied with
"ls -la" that its permissions changed (they did), but didn't solve anything.

I am new in linux, and any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at the point of execution, the variable is not defined; the script search for a file `/bin/tools/RunFunctions/`, not `/opt/openfoam222/bin/tools/RunFunctions`.

Notice that [non-interactive shells does not load .bashrc by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal), so the fact that the variable is defined when you use it in interactive is not a proof. Even if you are running the script from you shell, the variables are not exported to sub-shell by default, they need to be declared `export` to do that.

Try to add a line like

```
echo "DEBUG variable is $WM_PROJECT_DIR"
```

before the failing line in ./Allrun and check the output. If this is the problem, you should explicitly source the file in your script. Or add an

```
export WM_PROJECT_DIR
```

to pass it to subshells.

**Added** (after comments). Notice that you shouldn't explicitly source your `.bashrc` in your `.profile` (they have different meaning and the shell sources them in different occasions, [see for example here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html).)

Scripts (non-interactive) should never rely on your login shell to run. If they need specific files/definitions, the should `source` them explicitly. For what you know, it could be called even from a different type of shell or from no shell at all.

Comment: I have tried to 'export' the variable within the script and it gets it and uses it alright! -great.

Now what I see is that the script fails because the source has not been 'loaded'.

My ~/.profile sources my ~/.bashrc, which sources the /opt/openfoam222/etc/bashrc

I find there an odd variable definition such as: 
`foamInstall=/opt`
`: ${FOAM_INST_DIR:=$foamInstall}; export FOAM_INST_DIR`
(note the "`: `" before the $)
and few lines further... 
`export WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR=$FOAM_INST_DIR` 
`export WM_PROJECT_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/openfoam222` 

Any idea to source all this properly?

Comment: I am a little bit confused.

Comment: My `.profile` came from ubuntu12.04 written by default (I haven't touched it). It sources my ~/.bashrc by the following:
`# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi`
Furthermore I found in the OpenFoam 'Installation Guide' (http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php) the step that asks for sourcing the /opt/openfoam222/etc/bashrc within the ~/.bashrc file.
I have tried different tutorials and I get the same error everywhere.

Comment: I have just realized that I don't have my $HOME/bin directory (doesn't exist). I don't know if this might influence in anyway, I guess it doesn't, but still; it is not in my $PATH