# problem to update bash profile

Tags: environment-variables

Each time i work with a tool named criu, i set the path variable:

```
 PATH=$PATH:/home/th/criu-1.3-rc2; export PATH
```

to be able to run

```
criu dump
```

but when I close the terminal and open it, it does not work

i update the :

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/home/th/criu-1.3-rc2'  >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but the same problem persists

Comment: Either add the program to ~/bin or put that PATH in .profile . See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your **.bashrc** instead of **.bash_profile** that is used only for bash in interactive mode.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal) is a useful explanation.

Comment: PATH=$PATH:/home/th/criu-1.3-rc2; export PATH
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/home/th/criu-1.3-rc2"  >> ~/.bashrc   it works Thanks for answer :)