# problem with call command on local terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

When I make a ssh connection with root account to my desktop using putty and installed some programs. when I list that program type and press doubletab, will complete/list all associated commands.

Ex.
Putty - SSH - 192.168.1.5

```
root@192.168.1.5:~# apt-get install aircrack-ng 
root@192.168.1.5:~# ai<TAB><TAB> 
airbase-ng aireplay-ng aircrack-ng airmon-ng airdecap-ng airodump-ng airdecloak-ng airtun-ng airdecloak-ng...
```

Xrdp - session Xorg - 192.168.1.5

```
root@192.168.1.5:~# air<tab><tab>
aircrack-ng airdecloak-ng
```

Both are `root@192.168.1.5:~#`. I need understand this. Other thing its on xfc4-terminal run `ssh root@localhost` and `ssh root@192.168.1.5` do the same thing above respectively.

How can I push command in xfce4-terminal after installed this packages on ssh connection?

Same happens for the history commands.
Example:

- SSH Connection: Only shows history of this user in ssh.
- Local connection: Only shows the xfce4-terminal history. Dont show packages installed with ssh session.

I think its a 'session' association?

Comment: I'm not sure that will help but you can try `sudo updatedb` (it will take awhile).

Comment: How do you access root account in xfce4-terminal?

Comment: @muru I login via rdp (xrdp) enter root and pass the Xorg Graphic opens desktop. click on terminal icon. and get root@192.168.1.5:~#

Comment: You are using `root` as local account in graphical environment? This is completely wrong approach and some graphical applications may limit this behavior. You should create normal limited account and run only some commands as `root` by opening `xfce4-terminal` and run `sudo -s`, `su -` or similar command in it to become `root`.

Comment: @j123b567 Is not a problem because i run in live mode. Its porpose! Don't worry about security. I understand your attention! And thanks for remid that! +1

Comment: @danuel My comment is not just about security. Some programs have hardcoded `if running as root then limit features to minimum or do nothing`. So this is the reason why it is bad idea. It may cause lot of unexpected problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not root on the second case. You should run `sudo su` or `sudo -s` to become root in the `xfce4-terminal` and try again the `ai<tab><tab>`

---

EDIT:
You should probably put this line at the end of `/root/.bashrc`

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

More reading is here: 
[Why ~/.bash_profile is not getting sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)

Comment: Ok. Can I know the "what" and why?
In xfce4-terminal: 
root@192.168.1.5:~# air<tab><tab>
aircrack-ng airdecloak-ng
root@192.168.1.5:~#sudo -su
root@192.168.1.5:~# air<tab><tab>
airbase-ng     aireplay-ng aircrack-ng     airmon-ng 
airdecap-ng   airodump-ng      airtun-ng airdecloak-ng 

Both are root@192.168.1.5. I need understand this.
Other thing its on xfc4-terminal run: #ssh root@localhost and #ssh root@192.168.1.5 do the same thing above respectively.

Comment: There may be some issue with `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.profile`, ... You can try to print contents of PATH variable `echo $PATH` in both cases and they will differ.

Comment: On SSH session <br> root@kali:~# echo $PATH <br>
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin <br>
On Xorg-xfce4-terminal <br>
root@kali:~# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin <br>
WOW Some smoke!! How set same path of ssh session into xfce4-terminal?
thanks @j123b567

Comment: @danuel I have updated the answer, this should help you