# My PATH variable resets itself when closing terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I want to add texlive's directory to my PATH, so i type `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` and it update the PATH variable correctly. I can use commands listed in texlive path, and `echo $PATH` return the usual usr/bin AND texlive's path.

But when I close my terminal and open it again, it doesn't work anymore, and `echo $PATH` return `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin` (Which is also kinda weird...).

Tried to edit `.profile` or `.bashrc` (I put `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` at the end), but bash doesn't seems to read it on new terminals.

Comment: Please try to be more specific than *"it's not working"* - what did you try, exactly - and what happened?

Comment: ^ what steeldriver said, but you might find a solution here: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/301745)

Comment: Edited to explain a little bit more. @wjandrea : I tried solutions listed here, but it doesn't change anything, PATH keeps reseting itself

Comment: It was the "not working" after editing the .profile that was of interest.  What did you change in the .profile?  That is the usual place to make such changes.

Comment: Please note that if you change `PATH` by editing `~/.profile`, you need to relogin before it takes effect.

Comment: @ubfan1 I didn't alter anything in .profile, I just added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux` at the end of it. The command works afterwards if I save and source it, but PATH still resets itself when I close the terminal.

@GunnarHjalmarsson if I understood well, don't have to relogin if I do `source ~/.profile`. Just to be sure, I tried to reboot : still the same problem.

Comment: If you source a file, the commands in that file will only affect the current bash instance. So yes, you need to relogin if you want a persistent change of `PATH`. (Can't tell why a reboot wasn't sufficient for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `export PATH="$PATH:<YourPath>"` at the end of `~/.profile` and don't forget to delete `.bash_profile` if you have it, because bash doesn't look at `.profile` if `.bash_profile` exists (per [Why ~/.bash_profile is not getting sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal)).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. This worked.

Note: This would work only if you're using the bash shell.
Run **echo $SHELL** on your terminal. If your terminal returns **\bin\bash**, then you're using bash.

1. Remove **export PATH="$PATH:YourPath"** from .profile
2. Run **source .profile** on the terminal in the home directory [This updates the path variables]
3. Create .bashrc if it doesn't exit by running **nano .bashrc**
4. Enter **export PATH="$PATH:YourPath"** into the file .bashrc
5. Run **source .bashrc**

Your problem should be solved