# How to Source the .bash_profile?

Tags: command-line, python, bashrc, ssl, pip

I was following [this](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username) article to get rid of

`WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`
and whenever I'd do `. ~/.bash_profile` it would result in

```
-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So, I searched askUbuntu and find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal) and according to one of the solutions provided,

I went to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command tab and checked the "Run command as a login shell" option. But now as soon as I open any terminal I get the first two lines as

```
-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: /home/nikhil/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

and the same if run `. ~/.bash_profile`. Please help.

Comment: You have a problem with a missing double quote in your .bash_profile file - if you post the entire file contents we might be able to find the issue.

Comment: @ArturMeinild `cat ~/.bash_profile` is resulting in `export PATH="$PATH:/home/nikhil/Fluutter/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable/flutter/bin
` I can see there is a " missing. Could you please help in rectifying it?

Comment: You need to add a `"` at the end of the line (right after `bin`).