# Which bash profile file should I use for each scenario?

Tags: command-line, bash, login, .profile

I have seen many detailed explanations on how `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and the various other profile files interact, so I'm not after an explanation of how they fit together (I've read many such explanations and yet none of them answer how to approach the below). What I would really appreciate knowing is the best way or best practice or most rational way or most efficient way (clarity, logic, and efficiency are best in my mind) to achieve the following scenarios:

1. If I want a line of bash code that only runs on opening any new graphical terminals, which file should I put that code into?
2. If I want a line of bash code that only runs at login for any new interactive shells, where should I put that code?
3. If I want a line of bash code that opens in *both* graphical terminals *and* interactive login shells, which file should I put that code into?

• Important point: To emphasise, I would like the above such that these lines of code *only* be run upon opening a shell or terminal, and *not* to run during invocation of any old one-line `echo "Hello World!"` script that I startup. i.e. I want these to only apply when I *choose* to open a shell/terminal and then start typing and for other scripts to *not* include that. Should be simple, right?

I'm really confused by this because these really should be incredibly simple to answer, and yet, I've never seen an answer. I *have* seen lots of inscrutable answers about how we have to dotsource `.profile` from `.bashrc`, or maybe it's the other way around (depending on the weather) and "you have to read document x, and document y, and *then* it will all be clear!" - the answers get more and more convoluted, and it is difficult to get an answer to the above three scenarios: simply / clearly / unambiguously. Would really appreciate knowing simply which file to put each piece of code into such that it will run in that scenario? I don't mind if there is minimal framework required in achieving that also. i.e. "For scenario 3, add the code to `file-x` but to facilitate that you must also put the following `if-then-fi` block into `file-y`" but it would be a massive bonus if the answer for the three scenarios can be cross-platform (i.e. a one-for-all solution that applies to debian/ubuntu, centos/red hat, MacOS, suse, etc, and also to Gnome/KDE/MacOS etc for the graphical terminal). If there is no rational/logical way to achieve this, then that is disappointing to say the least, but hopefully I'm wrong! Hopefully someone is going to show me a clear, efficient, *hopefully* cross-platform (but I know that might be too much to ask), repeatable, simple, and unambiguous way to achieve the above.

Comment: Read `man bash`, the "`INVOCATION`" section to start. For the rest, look at the environment(`env|sort`) in each of the environments. E.g. graphical terminals have `$DISPLAY` defined. Read `man tty` for more differences. `bash` includes IF-THEN-ELSE, so it's a SMOP. Put your code in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

Comment: ok, willdo, but as above, if I put code in `.bashrc` then it will run on any instance of anything (*including* an invocation of a one-line `echo "Hello World!"` script!), right? That's pretty bizarre when you think about it, because if the point of the incomprehensible maze of profile files is *not* to give logical separation to such things, then what is the point?? Was the goal just to build as inscrutable a maze as possible with no clear approaches to anything? Would you say there is no clear approach / no way to answer my scenarios?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between your scenario 1 and 2. Bash uses the terms "login shell" and "interactive shell". How do these relate to your scenarios, and what do you mean exactly by "any new graphical terminal"?

Comment: See above, scenario 1 says "graphical terminal shell" and 2 says "interactive shell". "any new graphical terminal" is exactly what it says: I am in GNOME or KDE or MacOS or whatever, and I click on the terminal icon, or I press the "Activities" button and type "term" and click on the terminal icon. The following long discussion proves that they are different from interactive shells. https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal/1012937#1012937?newreg=8818dbcf69dd4fb7a8f25930d25fa3f7 in particular the discussion under geirha's answer.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion.

Scenario 1:
Put your command in `~/.bashrc` like this: `[[ "$TERM" == "xterm"* ]] && run-command` (test if terminal is xterm)

Scenario 2:
Put your command in `~/.bash_login` (remember to source `~/.bashrc` if you still want to run that)

Scenario 3:
Put your command in `~/.bashrc` like this: `[[ $- == *"i"* ]] && run-command` (test if shell is interactive)

I use these options in my `.bashrc`, for more or less the same purposes you want, from what I understand.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is *very* unfortunate that this is quite ambiguous and difficult to get answers to. I'm going to try out your solution, looks very good. Out of curiosity, would you say then that in general, you personally only modify `.bashrc` and `.bash_login` and leave all files under `/etc` alone?

Comment: For my own user profile, yes. If I had some settings that were global for all users, I could use `/etc/profile`.

Comment: It gets complicated because your scenarios are a mix of the state of the shell, and the state of the terminal, which are 2 completely different things. This is also why you need to test `$TERM`, and not only the state of the shell.

Comment: Agree, but you see how this is the normal state of how an averagely IT literate user might approach Linux. They will say "ok, I want to add something to my 'environment' that I can have available to me whenever I open a shell" and it is not apparently obvious that the state of an interactive shell via `ssh` should be somehow *different* from an interactive shell that they open when they are sitting at a GNOME desktop. I'm interested in how that can be communicated in an easily comprehensible way.

Comment: Note that creating a `~/.bash_login` file will stop `~/.bashrc` from running, unless you put code to run `~/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_login` file (as it is by default in `~/.profile` file)

Comment: You are of course right, and I added that to answer.

Comment: For 2 (bash code that only runs at login for any new interactive shell), would an alternative be to not use `.bash_profile` at all and instead do `[[ "$TERM" != "xterm"* ]] && run-command` in `.bashrc` (I'm thinking about what might be the simplest to implement and manage - managing one files maybe less work than managing two). My reasoning might be broken though...

Comment: Scenario 2 is specific for "login shells", and in this case it doesn't matter what the terminal is. So I don't believe it can easily be done any other way.

Comment: I believe that almost always, I want a common set of tools available to me whether I login via `ssh` or in a desktop `terminal` (scenario 3), so maybe I should just create a separate file `~/.custom` and source it in `~/.bashrc` with `[[ $- == *"i"* ]] && ~/.myprofile`, or even put that file as `/etc/custom` if multiple users will use then I just need to add that one line to `~/.bashrc`. Managing environment variables in one file and functions in another is not as easy to manage or automate.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` recognizes three shell states:

- login shell - shell instance that has been invoked directly by logging in to the server via eg. ssh or text console
- interactive shell - any shell where you can type commands, eg. shell started in graphical terminal. Login shell is also (usually) an interactive shell.
- non-interactive shell - this is usually shell invoked from within some program to run another program or command. As the name implies, in non-interactive shell there is no interaction with the user. For example, if you use ssh to run only a single command on a remote machine (like `ssh host.domain ls -l /etc`) then you are implicitly invoking a non-interactive shell on the remote machine and that shell in turn runs the command, and then quits.

How the startup files work:

- a **login shell** executes commands from `/etc/profile` (that's the global file for all users) and then looks for files `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or  `.profile` - in that order - in individual user's home directory, and executes commands from whichever file is found first. In Ubuntu by default only the `.profile` file exists, and by default it includes commands to execute contents of the `.bashrc` file also. However, you can remove the code to run `.bashrc` from the `.profile` file or you can create any of the other two files with the commands you need, and then `.profile` will not be run.
- an **interactive** (but **non-login**) shell executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` (that's global for all users) and then from `.bashrc` file in the individual user's home directory
- **non-interactive** shells started **locally** (ie. from within a program, or by typing `bash` in terminal window) do not run any of these files
- **non-interactive** shells started **from the network** (eg. in the above example where you run a command on remote machine via ssh) execute commands from `.bashrc` file in user's home directory only. However, the default Ubuntu `.bashrc` file contains a piece of code at the beginning that stops further execution if the shell is non-interactive.

There are some more subtleties in specific cases, but basically it works as above.

So the solution depend on whether you want to keep the current default contents of `.profile` and `.bashrc` files or not.

If you want to keep them:

- for case 1) you can use Artur's solution (but remember, your code will be run not only after login or after start of a terminal, but also whenever you start another shell instance, by eg. simply typing `bash` within a terminal session. If you want to avoid this, you should slightly modify the solution:
  `[[ "$TERM" == "xterm"* ]] && [ "$SHLVL" = "1" ] && run-command`
- for case 2), put your code in `.profile`
- for case 3), just put your code in `.bashrc` (only remember to insert it **below** the initial code that exits in case the shell is non-interactive). However, remember that similarly to case 1), your code will be run whenever you start another shell instance, so to avoid it it should be like `[ "$SHLVL" = "1" ] && run-command`

If you want to do it for all users and not just for yourself, use `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` files instead of `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

If you want to remove the defaults:

- rename `.bashrc` to something else (to be able to restore it later if you change your mind)
- create an empty `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` file
  and then:
- for case 1), do as above
- for case 2), put your code in `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` (whichever file you did create)
- for case 3), first add code to run `.bashrc` to your `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` file (whichever you did create), as it is not present there by default. Then use Artur's solution - however, similarly to case 1) above, optionally modify it to the form `[[ $- == *"i"* ]] && [ "$SHLVL" = "1" ] && run-command`

I do not recommend removing the defaults in case of system-wide files (`/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`) :)

Comment: `.bashrc` can be read, even if the shell is non-interactive - for instance when connecting via sftp. That's why the first if-statement in `.bashrc` by default is a loop that skips reading the file if the shell is non-interactive (and this is important if you want to use sftp - I've tried).

Comment: My solution for scenario 3 is "bulletproof", since you can then put it before the "return if non-interactive" if-statement, if you should somehow prefer that.

Comment: I forgot about the exit condition at the beginning of `.bashrc` :). I edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

- `~/.profile` to set my environment variables

  - this works in bash but also to expose the variables to other GUI apps
  - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables
  - .profile is bash's 3rd choice, so ensure you do not have either ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
- `~/.bashrc` for

  - aliases and functions
  - variables and settings for interactive shells

---

Note that the ~/.profile is not bash-specific, so don't use bash-specific commands. This means

```sh
# export FOO=bar      # bad
FOO=bar; export FOO   # good
```

Since my GUI terminal apps are all configured to use a login shell, in my ~/.profile I put this:

```sh
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

---

Also, I like to keep my PATH tidy, with no duplicates, so instead of using

```sh
PATH="$PATH:/some/path/1"
PATH="/some/path/2:$PATH"
```

I have

```sh
pathmunge () {
    case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            [ ! -d "$1" ] && return
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
    esac
}

# then
pathmunge "/some/path/1" after
pathmunge "/some/path/2" before
pathmunge "/some/path/1" before   # already in PATH, no changes made
```